# Firebase fetch different results with the same code

Tags: swift, firebase

I am new to firebase and I have experienced getting different fetched results before and after cleaning build folder. I would like to know is it common to getting different results with the same code? In addition, after I delete a node from the database on Firebase, my app still fetch the deleted post. How would I solve that issue?

And I found out that if I do not signout of a user's account and I delete the user's database. When I reload the app, I got stuck on home tab instead of arriving on Signin page and can't logout. How can I solve that?

EDIT (add code and pic):
[image: user-feed -> uid -> postId]

This is my user-feed which contains uid followed by postId. These four postIds are from two uids, but I can only fetch currentUid's posts. My code to fetch is:

```
static func fetchUser(with uid: String, completion: @escaping (User) -> ()) {
    USER_REF.child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        guard let userDictionary = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> else { return }
        let user = User(uid: uid, dictionary: userDictionary)
        completion(user)
    }
}

static func fetchPost(with postId: String, completion: @escaping (Post) -> ()) {
    POSTS_REF.child(postId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in

        guard let postDictionary = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> else { return }
        guard let ownerUid = postDictionary["ownerUid"] as? String else {return}

        self.fetchUser(with: ownerUid, completion: { (user) in
            var post = Post(user: user, dictionary: postDictionary)

            post.postId = postId

         //... ...
```

My code to fetch posts on feedController is:

```
        guard let currentUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}
        //USER_FEED_REF points to "user-feed"
        USER_FEED_REF.child(currentUid).queryLimited(toLast: 3).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in    
            self.collectionView.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
            guard let allObjects = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else {return}
            allObjects.forEach({ (snapshot) in
                print(snapshot) //only currentUid's postId shown
                let postId = snapshot.key
                Database.fetchPost(with: postId, completion: {(post) in
                    self.posts.append(post)
               //... ...
```

When I tried to fetch last week I got all posts from "user-feed" under certain uid (see picture above), however, when I tried the app in a new database I can only fetch currentUid's posts.

As for frozen app after removing user's database, I deleted the currentUid's database (e.g. "user" node which contains profileImageUrl, username and so on) before I signed out in the app. When I rebuilt the app, I went directly to Homepage instead of Signin Page. Since there was no user's data avialable, username, images were not shown and I couldn't logout.

Comment: Please attach the related code so that we can better understand what's going on

Comment: Where are you setting the currentUid?

Comment: Sorry forgot to put it there. I just edited. It is before "USER_FEED_REF..." on top of the last coding area

Comment: I don't know why you are getting the same values.. But I see an error where you are not calling your completion in fetch user if the userDictionary is nil. This might be causing you to be unable to logout.

Comment: Firebase authentication and a /users node are unrelated; you can delete every user in your /users node and every user can still authenticate. What happens after that is determined by your code and Firebase Rules. Second thing: do you have [Firebase persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities) on? If so, you may be reading cached local data. Lastly; it's important that questions include code that duplicates the issue. There's no code in your question that actually deletes anything or responds to something being deleted. Can you clarify what you are asking?